# ¿Por qué "el cierre" en vez de "el cerrado"?

Tags: sustantivos, participio

> Stack Exchange permite a sus usuarios decidir tanto sobre el **cierre** como sobre el **borrado** de preguntas.

En la oración anterior, *cierre* y *borrado* son sustantivos que se refieren a la acción de *cerrar algo* y de *borrar algo*, respectivamente.

El caso de *borrado* entiendo que es un uso habitual del participio: acción de *borrar* → el *borrado*.
Pero siguiendo la misma norma, si el participio de *cerrar* es *cerrado*, **¿por qué decimos *el cierre* en vez de *el cerrado*?**

¿Serían correctas las siguientes?

> Stack Exchange permite a sus usuarios decidir tanto sobre el **cerrado** como sobre el **borrado** de preguntas.
>
> Stack Exchange permite a sus usuarios decidir tanto sobre el **cierre** como sobre el **borre** de preguntas.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

La norma es que, cuando se requiere un sustantivo, se debe utilizar el sustantivo o, a lo sumo, el infinitivo. En el caso de "cerrar", el sustantivo es "cierre" y por lo tanto es el término que debe utilizarse cuando se requiere una palabra de esa categoría gramatical.

En el caso de la acción o resultado de "borrar", el sustantivo es "borrado", de la misma forma que la acción de "correr" puede ser una "corrida" (ej. corrida bancaria), la acción de sentarse (a modo de protesta) puede ser una "sentada",  la acción de testar (tachar) se llama "testado", el acto de mirar, "mirada", la acción de lavar, "lavado", la acción de secar, "secado", la acción de llamar puede ser, según el caso, "llamado" o "llamada", etc. (nótese que varios son femeninos).

Existen casos en que existe un sustantivo propiamente dicho y otro derivado de participio para designar diferentes significados: "siembra" (la acción de sembrar) y "sembrado" (una plantación); "tintura" (la sustancia utilizada para teñir) y "teñido" (la acción de teñir).

Cuando no existe un sustantivo "propiamente dicho", la lengua ofrece el mecanismo del participio (muchas veces en la forma femenina) a fin de suplir la falta del sustantivo, inclusive para generar un significado diferenciado, por ejemplo "pintada" vs. "pintura".

Comment: La etimología no es mi fuerte, @walen, pero el sentido común me indica que, cuando no existe un sustantivo "propiamente dicho", la lengua ofrece el mecanismo del participio (muchas veces en la forma femenina) a fin de suplir la falta del sustantivo, inclusive para generar un significado diferenciado, por ejemplo "pintada" vs. "pintura".

Answer (score 2):

Hay muchas maneras de formar los *«sustantivos deverbales que expresan acción y efecto»* además del [participio pasado](http://dle.rae.es/?id=0nMfsj7) (def. 3) (como en *el cerr**ado***), y entre estos hay *-e* (como en *el cierr**e***):

> [**-e**](http://dle.rae.es/?id=EIXWV81)
>
> 1. `suf.` En sustantivos deverbales, significa 'acción y efecto'. *Corte, avance, goce, combate.*

Los más comunes sufijos así son:

- [-erio](http://dle.rae.es/?id=G2NeHid), [-ción](http://dle.rae.es/?id=9I27Gyi), [-anza](http://dle.rae.es/?id=30HXD1D), [-miento](http://dle.rae.es/?id=PDgi3bc), [-dura](http://dle.rae.es/?id=EHGi0dJ), [-ncia](http://dle.rae.es/?id=QJb1Ewu)

pero hay aún más formas:

- **Infinitivo:** poder (poder), saber (saber)
- **Participio pasado:** estar (estado), decir (dicho)

  - **Forma femenina/modificada:** ver (vista), perder (pérdida)
- **Raíz + sufijo femenino:** hablar (habla), ayudar (ayuda)
- **Raíz + sufijo masculino:** cantar (canto), trabajar (trabajo)

etc

---

<sup>[***La derivación en español:*** *verbos derivados y sustantivos verbales*](https://books.google.co.uk/books/about/La_derivaci%C3%B3n_en_espa%C3%B1ol.html?id=CcxQMwAACAAJ), Jesús Pena Seijas</sup>

Comment: @walen Bien, no creo que haya un porqué - la lengua no es algo diseñado científicamente, es llena de 'incongruencias' así. Hay varias formas de hacer un sustantivo de un verbo, por ejemplo, *pensar* > *pensamiento*, *cantar* > *canto*, *perder* > *pérdida*, *hablar* > *habla*, *tener* > *tenencia* etc. No son siempre (derivados de) los participios pasados.

Answer (score 0):

La palabra "cierre" se puede utilizar para expresar una acción de cerrar algo, y también como un sustantivo masculino, en cuyo caso "cierre" es un mecanismo que sirve para cerrar algo o el efecto de cerrar alguna cosa. Ejemplo: *El cierre de la puerta esta roto*.
Sin embargo "cerrado" es algo que no tiene abertura o ha sido tapado. Ejemplo: *La caja esta cerrada.*
Más información:  [cerrado](https://es.thefreedictionary.com/cierre) y [cierre](https://es.thefreedictionary.com/cerrado).